# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} (0,9999+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1,00001-\frac{1}{n})^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Find $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(0,9999+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n \\ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1,00001-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Tried few methods but could not find solution.

Comment: $(1+ \frac{1}{x})^x \to e$ when $x \to +\infty$

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle That identity is not useful here, in the first limit it's $\frac1{\sqrt n}$ and not $\frac1n$ and in the second limit we've got sign differences

Comment: @Darksonn with some adapatation, it can help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For large $n$ the expression $0.9999+1/\sqrt{n}$ is less than, say $0.99995$, hence the limit is 0. In the second case you can think about, say, $1.000005$ and the limit is $\infty$.

For those who do not understand and downvote: and then use the sandwich (squeeze) theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem.

Comment: You can't evaluate limits by trying values close to the limit.

Comment: @Darksonn - It's a perfectly valid argument.

Comment: Okay, I get it now, maybe you should have mentioned that it was because of the exponential.

Comment: @VirrageS Yes, as it is not less than the limit of $(1+\varepsilon)^n$.